# Using Sphinx index with additional relationship crossing

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, sphinx

I'm implementing a search through a db that involves a text search inside names in addition to crossing with additional filters. Sphinx seems like a better tool than MySQL full-text search to solve the text search feature, but I'm not sure if it will enable to do the cross selects in addition to the text match field. Does it have such an option? Will MySQL Full-text be more suitable?

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt support joins as such. Because sphinx lives outside mysql - its a seperate system.

But the sphinx index itself, can be built with joins, so when creating the index, you join all the required tables, to put all the relevent data into the index.

Bascially you precompute a index that 'does everything', and jsut filter as required. (we technically sometimes it requires multiple indexes, but only in advanced cases)

Personally would suggest that sphinx is well worth the investment. Will be a bit of work to get it running, but it will pay off both in performance, and flexiblity. Will be able to queries, you dont even imagine right now. (Can you tell I am a really avid fan of sphinx)